# Tricky latent parameter problem

Tags: bayesian, latent-variable

I'm reinterpreting the data of some colleagues to see if I can't get at heterogeneity in grouped outcomes.  Start with a decay process with two pools:

$$
C_{it} = P_i e^{-k_{i}^{fast}t} + (1-P_i)e^{-k_i^{slow}t}
$$

The amount of $C$ remaining in situation $i$ after time $t$ is an exponential function of two pools $P + (1-P) = C_0 \equiv 1$.  Those two pools have different decay rates, $k_i^{fast}$ and $k_i^{slow}$, which in turn are functions of observable parameters and error, 
$$k_i^{slow} = f^{slow}(X_i)+\epsilon_i^{slow}$$ 
and

$$k_i^{fast} = f^{fast}(X_i)+\epsilon_i^{fast}$$

If I knew the different proportions in the fast and slow pools for each situation i.e. if I knew $P_i$, I'd be set, because then I could calculate $k^{fast}$ and $k^{slow}$.  I've got some intuition that $P_i$ is correlated with $X_i$, but I don't really know the function mapping one to the other.

This problem is either intractable, or it requires some Bayesian methods that I'm not too familiar with.  Could I specify some sort of prior over the function mapping $X_i$ to $P_i$, and then back out a range of potential values for $\hat k^{fast}$ and $\hat k^{slow}$ and $\hat P_i$?  I guess what I really want are multivariate posteriors, because I'll use them to sample from in a monte carlo study.

Besides $X$, I've got data on $C_t$ and, perhaps importantly, the least-biased estimate of the average $P$ for my whole sample (from some curve-fitting software that they used) was about .17.

Any ideas for ways forward would be really appreciated.  If this is a solvable problem, ideas for how to use R to implement would be great -- I haven't really invested much in Bayesian methods so I don't really know the software.